# Toggle screen rotation only for my app

Tags: android, screen-rotation

I am developing an android app. I want to toggle screen rotation only for my app. I am currently able to toggle screen rotation for my device. But I want to toggle screen rotation only for my app.

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle your app orientation by using the following

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

just set listener to the view on whose click you want to set the rotation. This will work even when your device rotation is off.

Comment: What I want is that irrespective of my devices rotation setting, I should be able to lock of unlock rotation for my app. This will actually set the rotation but I want that if right now I am in portrait mode and I click the lock button then it should lock the rotation and remain in portrait mode. If I am in landscape mode and I click the lock button then it should remain in landscape mode.

Comment: Ok so all you want is that irrespective to device rotation your app must rotate as per the orientation you have set. right?

Comment: right...So I think first I need to detect current orientation mode and then based on whether the rotation is locked or not I have to decide which mode to set.

Comment: This code will do that only the one which changes device orientation is like this 
 Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
    Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 1);

The code i mentioned earlier will set the orientation of app not device.

Comment: But where should I put all this code?? On button click basically I just want to change the flag value. The orientation should change when phone is moved to change the orientation. Is there any event for this?

Comment: That is a different concept you have to create broadcast receiver for that well i am not sure what you want? You wanted to change the orientation via code the above code does that only just add this to the onclick of view to  click of which you wanted to change orientation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69294/discussion-between-ankit-and-sumant-raj).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to be able to "pin" current orientation?

At the time when user pushes the pin button, issue

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
```

To get current orientation and then

```
setRequestedOrientation();
```

Note that the functions use different constants.

Comment: But where should I put all this code?? On button click basically I just want to change the flag value. The orientation should change when phone is moved to change the orientation. Is there any event for this?

Comment: You place it on buttonn click. If enabled, you request the orientation, if disabled, you remove the request.